# Para que serve exatamente a barra invertida ( \ ) no Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatação

Eu enviei uma aplicação ao GitHub escrita em Python que foi atualizada por alguém que dizia ter formatado o código adequadamente. Depois de começar a ver as alterações, eu fiquei assustado pensando que ele tinha estragado o meu programa, pois este trecho do meu código original:

```
self.__bg_image = self.getPhotoImage(image_path=self.image_path,width=self.__width,height=self.__height,closeAfter=True)[0]
```

havia se transformado nisto:

```
self.__bg_image = \
self.getPhotoImage(image_path=self.image_path, width=self.__width, height=self.__height, closeAfter=True)[0]
```

Então antes de reclamar, eu testei o código atualizado e para a minha surpresa, ele funcionou perfeitamente sem nenhuma alteração aparente no resultado final.

Depois disso eu fiquei muito curioso para saber como exatamente funciona essa barra invertida que eu nunca tinha visto antes. Alguém aí pode me explicar ?

Comment: A versão do Python é a 3.6 antes que alguém pergunte.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## `\` "solta" no código

A barra invertida fora de strings serve para indicar uma mudança de linha sem sair do contexto da linha atual (isso é - depois de uma `\`, você pode continuar a linha atual na linha de baixo normalmente)

```
resultado = variavel1 * variavel2 + \
    funcao3(variavel4) + variavel5
```

Em linguagens com a sintaxe derivada do C (Java, Javascript, PHP, C#, Objective C, C++, etc...) , expressões podem se extender por várias linhas,e o que define o final de uma expressão é o `;`. Em Python, a mudança de linha faz o papel do `;` (que é opcional em Python, mas recomendado apenas nas raríssimas vezes em que se decide colocar dois comandos na mesma linha)

Por outro lado, a sensação para alguns programadores Python ao poder continuar uma linha apenas com o `\` é que as coisas ficam meio "soltas". : ex.: se entrar uma linha em branco ou comentário acontece um erro de sintaxe, sendo que se esse recurso não estiver sendo usado, sempre é possível deixar uma linha em branco, em qualquer ponto). Então, a preferência, sempre que possível, inclusive a recomendação em guias de estilo, é colocar um par extra de parênteses em torno de expressões que fiquem grandes demais.

Se a expressão está dentro de um par parênteses, é permitido quebras de linha a vontade, até o `)` - e ele ainda marca o final da expressão exato - a sensação é que as coisas ficam mais amarradas.

```
resultado = (variavel1 * variavel2 + 
    funcao3(variavel4) + variavel5  
)
```

A preferência pelos parênteses, com os anos, foi tão maior que fizeram inclusive mudanças na sintaxe da linguagem para aceitar parênteses onde não fazia sentido antes (por exemplo, no comando `import`).

```py
from projeto import (
    classe1, 
    classe2,
    classe3
)
```

Hoje em dia, a única estrutura que ainda precisa do `\` para quebrar a linha no caso de linhas muito compridas é o comando `with` com vários context managers - não dá pra agrupa-los com parênteses, por que para o runtime do Python, isso seria indistinguível de uma tupla.

```py
with open(nome_arq1) as arq1, \
    open(nome_arq2) as arq2:
```

O `\` ainda pode ser bonitinho e é legal de usar ao se optar por dividir uma
string muito grande em várias linhas - mas eu não usaria em outros casos.

Nesse caso aí, e que ver a intenção desse "alguém" que atualizou o seu código - há uma prática de abrir PRs com formatação de código por que aí a pessoa engana as estatísticas de contribuição de código em um projeto, ou para seu portfólio.

Linhas mais curtas são legais - mas a forma recomendada é colocando expressões grandes em parênteses, não com o `\`.

E por fim, mas não por último, em 2019 se tornou popular uma ferramenta de formatação de código que ajuda em muito com isso - ela ajusta a formatação do código para as recomendações de estilo desejadas, sem que os desenvolvedores tenham que perder seu tempo com isso-  se chama "black" - https://github.com/psf/black - pode ser usada pela linha de comando, ou integrada a uma IDE.

No caso que você colocou no exemplo da pergunta, em particular, em vez de ganhar umas poucas colunas quebrando a linha logo após o nome da variável, o ideal é colocar em várias linhas - aproveitando que já existem
parênteses na chamada ao método. Isso é, em vez de:

```
self.__bg_image = \
self.getPhotoImage(image_path=self.image_path, width=self.__width, height=self.__height, closeAfter=True)[0]
```

fazer:

```
self.__bg_image = self.getPhotoImage(
    image_path=self.image_path,
    width=self.__width,
    height=self.__height, 
    closeAfter=True
)[0]
```

## O `\` dentro de strings

Dentro de qualquer tipo de string no Python - isso é, no 
no arquivo ".py" , texto que vem entre qualquer tipo 
de par de aspas dentre os válidos que são `', ", ''', """` e possivelmente combinadas um ou mais dentre os prefixos `u, b, f` (mas com não do prefixo `r`), a barra invertida tem um papel completamente diferente.

Nesse caso, Python também pegou um comportamento da linguagem C - a  `\` dentro de strings serve como caractere de Escape - significando que ela pode ser combinada com o próximo (ou próximos) caracteres para formar um caracter completamente diferente.

```
Python 3.8.0+ (heads/3.8:d04661f, Oct 24 2019, 09:19:45) 
[GCC 7.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a = "c:\indios"
>>> b = "c:\ndios"
>>> "\\" in a
True
>>> "\\" in b
False
>>> print(a, b)
c:\indios c:
dios
```

Isso é - dependendo do que vem depois da "\" ela *deixa de existir* dentro do texto da string, e vira outro código:

```py
>>> a = "\t"
>>> b = "\i"
>>> len(a)
1
>>> len(b)
2
>>> ord(a[0])
9
>>> ord(b[0])
92
```

Para garantir que ela exista como "\" mesmo, é recomendado sempre usar a forma `\\` (duas barras) - duas barras se combinam em uma único caracter. No Windows, como a  `\` é usada no cmd para separar diretórios isso fica muito mais perigoso  - por que um programa pode funcionar ou nao dependendo da primeira letra do nome de um arquivo dentro de uma pasta. (Só não é pior por que se o nome do arquivo estiver em uma variável, em vez de escrito direto em uma única string dentro do arquivo .py, a substituição não acontece)

### Sequências úteis com `\` dentro de strings:

- `\n` - essa é a mais usada, indica uma quebra de linha (caracter especial NEWLINE, de código hexadecimal 0x0a) - se usado num print, gravado num arquivo, etc, faz o texto mudar de linha e continuar na linha de baixo
- `\t` Caractere especial TAB (hex 0x09): um espaçador especial que faz a impressão do texto avançar até a próxima "coluna de tabulação" (em geral, múltiplos de 8, mas é configurável) - muito importante quando os computadores tinham muito menos memória e fazia muita diferença ter 
  um único caracter com código 9, gastando um único byte, no lugar de 
  até 8 caracteres de espaço - em arquivos de texto contendo tabelas, etc...
  Seu uso hoje pode confundir muita gente, por que o número de espaços que ele gera é variável - só recomendo o uso por quem souber *exatamente* o que está fazendo (e sempre configurar o editor de programação para usar "espaços" em vez de "tabs"):

```
>>> for i in range(15):
...     print(f"{'#' * i}\t#")
... 
        #
#       #
##      #
###     #
####    #
#####   #
######  #
####### #
########        #
#########       #
##########      #
###########     #
############    #
#############   #
##############  #
>>>
```

- `\b` BACKSPACE (\x08) esse é interessantíssimo: faz a impressão "voltar" um caractere para trás. Pode ser usado em programas simples de linha de comando para imprimir porcentagens de progresso, re-escrevendo o valor com o print (desculpe, não vou fazer filminho, mas o código em Python abaixo pode ser colado num interpretador interativo:

```
import time
for i in range(0, 100, 5):
    print("\b\b\b\b\b\b", i, "%",  sep="", end="", flush=True)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

- `\r` - "carriage return" - 0x0d - nos sistemas atuais faz a impressão voltar para  o começo da linha atual, mas sem mudar de linha (parecido com o \b)
- `\\` uma `\` normal - que garantidaente funciona

```
>>> print("\\")
\
```

- `\"` - a barra pode ser usada para se colocar aspas do mesmo tipo usado para abrir a string dentro da string:

```
>>> a = "teste: \"alo\""                                                                                                                                                       

>>>  print(a)                                                                                                                                                                   
teste: "alo"
```

- `\` sozinha, no final de uma linha, mas dentro de uma string: tem o mesmo efeito que a `\` usado no código: o Python ignora o caractere de mudança de linha depois da "\" e faz o texto continuar sem quebra. Isso funciona em qualquer estilo de strings, mas já que a string vai usar múltiplas linhas do programa, o ideal é usar strings com aspas triplas, que podem ter múltiplas linhas no arquivo .py:

```
>>> a = """ Vou contar uma história:\
...  em uma linha só"""
>>> print(a)
Vou contar uma história: em uma linha só
```

- `\xHH` - permite a impressão de qualquer caractere unicode de código até 255, direto pelo seu valor hexadecimal.

```
>>> print("\xb1")                                                                                                                                                              
±
```

- `\uHHHH` - como o `\x` mas usa quatro dígitos hexa, permitindo qualquer caractere unicode do "BMP" (Base Multilingual Plane) - com mais de 60000 caracteres possíveis. Além de quase todos os sistemas de escritas do mundo, nessa faixa também já temos alguns emojis

```
>>> print ("\u2665")                                                                                                                                                           
♥
```

- `\UHHHHHHHH` - 'U' maiúsculo usa oito dígitos hexa, permitindo qualquer caractere unicode *at all* (apesar de o máximo definido caber em somente 6 dígitos hexa)

```
print ("\U0001F600 \U0001F46A")
```

(esses emojis não vao funcionar no CMD padrão do Windows,mas baixe a nova aplicação de ["terminal" na windows store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-terminal-preview/9n0dx20hk701?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) se estiver nesse sistema operacional - em Mac e Linux eles aparecem normalmente)

## `\` dentro de strings com prefixo `r` -

O prefixo "r" foi criado por que as vezes a transformação da `\` não é desejada, e pode ser inconveniente - nesse caso, *quase* todas as combinações especiais de  `\` são ignoradas, e ela sempre e inserida como foi digitada.

Isso é importante para poder digitar expressões regulares, ou outros
textos em que o "\" seja um caractere significativo - por exemplo - em nomes
de arquivos no Windows:

```py
>>> a = "\xb1"
>>> b = r"\xb1"
>>> print(a, b)
± \xb1
```

No caso de expressões regulares, a `\` pode significar muitas coisas diferentes - em geral ela é usada para "escape" também - mas o motor de expressões regulares tem que saber "o que" vem depois da "\" - sem o prefixo `r"` o Python traduz os caracteres, como acima, já na compilação, e o motor de expressão regular veria só os códigos já transformados.

Comment: Nossa... você foi muito mais além do que eu estava precisando kkk. Obrigado pela resposta jsbueno <3

Comment: aproeitei o embalo, por que aí já fica documentado - mesmo em inglês é dificil achar tudo isso num lugar só.  (A dica da `\` no final de uma linha _dentro_ de uma string, por exemplo, é algo que pode confundir até desenvolvedores experientes na linguagem)

Comment: Ainda faltaram os codecs especiais que podem interpretar as "\" - mas acabou o gás aqui. :-)

Comment: Eu só n entendi muito bem a parte que você falou de práticas de abrir "PRs" etc. Dá pra explicar melhor ?

Comment: PR = Pull Request - é a forma como outras pessoas fazem modificações em projetos a que não tem acesso direto no github. Ou como é que foi que a pessoa alterou o seu projeto lá?

Comment: Ata, eu não sabia do que se tratava a sigla "PR".