# Qual a funções dessas barras invertidas nessa sentença? http.POST("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");

Tags: c, json

```
// start connection and send HTTP header and body
int httpCode = http.POST("{\"hello\":\"world\"}");
```

Comment: Creio que você deveria estudar "qual a função da barra invertida?" e caracteres de escape.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve exatamente a barra invertida ( \ ) no Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426841/para-que-serve-exatamente-a-barra-invertida-no-python)

Comment: Especificamente sobre JSON: O delimitador de uma string em `JSON` sempre é `"`. Como sua string já usa `"` no código, você precisa usar `\"`  para escapar a string que vai dentro da aspas.

Answer (score 3):

Essas barras invertidas servem para escapar o próximo carácter, ou seja, ele será entendido literalmente como `"`, e não como fechamento de `string`.

Sem essas barras, o conteúdo dentro da sua função seria uma `string` inválida.

Comment: Compreendi perfeitamente! Obrigado ;)